# jQuery: Binding "CTRL+A" to only select specific area only

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

What I'm trying to do is, when CTRL+A is pressed, the shortcut for select all; I don't want it select everything but only a specific area (like everything inside containers with a class of xyz). However, I'm not able to get anything working. Even just using `select()` is not working. Example:

```
$("table").select();
```

I tried using a js solution I found here, but it was binding it if a certain area is active and I couldn't work around it. This is the code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById('table'));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I have created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zpd8yLn7/

What I want is that the text inside `class="class"` be selected whenever CTRL+A is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are open to a purely css solution: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpd8yLn7/2/)

```
body > :not(.class) {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

References:

[CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

[CSS-Tricks - *not(s)*](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

Comment: This looks good and works. Is this compatible with all modern browsers?

Comment: Yes. Chrome 6.0+, Firefox, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+,  IE10+